# TYPO3 4.5 - Multilingual - How can I use the second Language as default?

Tags: typo3, translation, default, typoscript

how can I set my 'second' language at my TYPO3 Website (4.5.x) to default?

I have `ID0 = german`, `ID1 = english` and `ID2 = spanish`
At the moment, if there's no translation TYPO3 will show the default language (0=german)

Here's my TS

```
# multilingual
##################
config.linkVars = L
config.uniqueLinkVars = 1

# no translation go to default
config.sys_language_mode = content_fallback

# not translated elements, show default
config.sys_language_overlay = 1

#config.sys_language_overlay = hideNonTranslated

# German / default :
config.sys_language_uid = 0
config.language = de
config.locale_all = de_DE.UTF8


# English :
[globalVar = GP:L = 1]
config.sys_language_uid = 1
config.language = en
config.locale_all = en_EN.UTF8
config.htmlTag_langKey = en
[global]

# Spanish :
[globalVar = GP:L = 2]
config.sys_language_uid = 2
config.language = es
config.locale_all = es_ES.UTF8
config.htmlTag_langKey = es
[global]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution for your problem is the attribute sys_language_mode
You can define the fallback for each language.

For example in your case

```
[globalVar = GP:L2]
config {
sys_language_uid = 2
language = es
locale_all = es_ES.UTF-8
htmlTag_langKey = es
sys_language_mode = content_fallback;1,0
}
[global]
```

This setup the content_fallback followed by the ordering of language_uid that should be used for fallback.

For detailed documentation read the TSREF
http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Setup/Config/Index.html#sys-language-mode

Cheers
Christian